# How to assign space for @property variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables

I am still new to objective-c and I need some insight about variable declaration.
The point of my program is to read a message delivered in several `NSData` parts. Whenever the program receive a `NSData` it adds it to the already partially complete message as unsigned chars. This means that the message buffer must be define as a property of the `viewController`:

```
@property unsigned char* receiveBuf;
@property int bufSize;
```

At that point the program has a `NSData` object named data, and treat it like this:

```
int len = [data length];
unsigned char* tempBytebuf = (unsigned char*)[data bytes];
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){                           //read all bytes
    if (tempBytebuf[i] == 0x7E) {                       //this char means start of package
        _bufSize = 0;
    }
    else if (tempBytebuf[i] == 0x7D) {                  //this char means end of package
        [self readMsgByte:_receiveBuf :_bufSize];
    }
    else {                                              //any other char is to be put in the message
        _receiveBuf[_bufSize++] = tempBytebuf[i];       //Error happens here
    }
}
```

if I proceed like this it will result in an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
If I could tell the program to reserve space for the buffer it would solve the problem:

```
@property unsigned char receiveBuf[256];
```

but it seems I can't do this with `@properties`.
Is there a way of assigning that space in the `ViewDidLoad()` for example or somewhere else?
Thanks for your support!

EDIT 1:

It seems I just found a solution in some of my previous codes, I should have declare my char table in the implementation instead.

```
@implementation ViewController
{
     unsigned char msgBuf[256];
}
```

Still if someone could tell me the real difference between the `@property` and `implementation` space for variable declaration that would prevent me from doing other mistakes like this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try using NSString in your case instead of cahracter array and perform concatenation of strings using NSString API ?

Comment: @saury: I can't use NSString because my NSData contains char that are not displayable by ASCII formatting like 0x00.

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu You'll need to tell us the range of characters supported by your messaging system.  We can see that `0x7d` and `0x7e` have special meaning and you have hinted at `0x00` as well so tell us the whole story.  The solution to this problem lies in using `NSString` (or `NSMutableString`), as already suggested, and getting away from statically-allocated buffers.

Comment: @trojanfoe: In the NSData i can have any value from 0x00 to 0xFF. I want to be able to use the full range of chars to have smaller NSData. If i can use the very efficient API of NSString while conserving easily all my values that would be great of course. I also want to be able to do easy comparison between my chars and for example 0x7E.

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You have "special characters" so you cannot use `0x00` to `0xff` can you?

Comment: NSString is not suitable, it can only work with data that is encoded in UTF-8 or some other string encoding, and is fairly slow/inefficient. You want NSData or NSMutableData. That can store any value of any size (it doesn't even need to fit in RAM. I have an app (on Mac OS X) that works with several hundred gigabyte NSData values, stored on disk).

Comment: @ trojanfoe: Why not? ^^ I just want pure Hex values to save storage place and keep fast transmission of NSData
@AbhiBeckert: thats exactly what I am doing. Thanks for the tips, I will look deeper on the NSMutableData then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you needed to declare that as `unsigned char*`, then malloc/calloc/realloc/free are your friends.

In reality, making that ivar `NSMutableData` and using APIs like `-appendBytes:length:` should be all that's necessary.

Comment: Great thank you Justin I'll look into it. I'll mark your answer as correct. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use NSMutableData:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableData *recievedData;
```

It provides a nice wrapper around an arbitrary piece of memory who's contents and length can change at any time - and most importantly it fits in perfectly with the objective-c runtime and memory management.

Just create an empty (0 length) data object like this:

```
self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

And then at any time you can do:

```
[self.recivedData appendBytes:bytes length:length];
```

Or:

```
[self.recievedBytes appendData:anotherNSDataObj];
```

From there you can read it with the getBytes: method.

There are other ways to do it, by declaring lower level instance variables, but @property is the modern approach. The older style of instance variable is able to what you tried, but we are moving away from them and it will probably be deprecated soon.

Comment: Thanks again Abhi that is definitely what I was looking for. I still need few reputation to give you an up vote sorry about that.